# should i update with results?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

So I've tried a recipe suggestion that I got from this site. 2 or 3 people have asked if I've done it yet. It turned out a great success and I have good pictures. Is it appropriate to share the results? How? Should I just edit the question with a result?

Here's the question: [How can I make a chocolate cup that looks like the seaweed on a sushi roll?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/how-can-i-make-a-chocolate-cup-that-looks-like-the-seaweed-on-a-sushi-roll)

Answer (score 6):

Sure, please do!

I don't think it belongs in the question, it might be confusing for future readers. A comment doesn't let you share the actual images inline.

I think you should just answer your own question with the results.

Comment: FWIW, I like the idea of adding an answer.  If the point of the site is to build a body of cooking knowledge, this seems like a good way to do it.

Comment: Make the answer CW though, unless it adds new information that's not in the other answers

Comment: What if the question was just about part of the entire dish? Describing how it came out is answering a much larger question than I initially asked.

Comment: Seems like the separate answer muddles the picture of possible solutions, especially if you're just stating which of the answers worked (and hopefully that's marked as accepted). I see this done on SO sometimes, though perhaps mostly by people without enough points to properly comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's no prescribed methodology for these sorts of things; the fact that you accepted the answer already indicates that it's the answer that worked for you.

If you can summarize in a short comment, I would just add a comment to the answer.  If you learned a few things during the process that you think would make the answer better, I might actually edit the answer.  If you think there's way too much information for any of that, add your own answer and link to the "real" answer that it references.

The only thing I *wouldn't* do is edit the question, because it lacks context and makes the question more difficult to read/understand.

Comment: In the case of my question, I was asking about one aspect of the dish. There seemed to be quite a lot of interest in the general dish rather than the specific aspect I was asking about. So an explanation of the dish goes well beyond the initial question. I could ask another question on the broader dish and then answer it myself, but that might be too much of a recipe request. I've updated this question with a link to the relevant question.